# How can I remove the Mojave download without installing it?

Tags: macos, install, mac-appstore, mojave

I accidentally clicked the upgrade message, thinking I was upgrading something else, which downloaded Mojave.

I was then presented with a window to install Mojave.  I don't want to install Mojave. It appeared I could not close the window, only minimize it.  But once I did minimize it I was able to right-click and select Quit.

I would like to completely remove whatever was downloaded because I'm afraid it will install without my consent. Any solutions to remove the download?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be in Applications, as "Install macOS Mojave" - just in case you were looking for it under "M".

The installer is simply an app, so like any app, just put it in the trash and empty the trash.

Comment: It won't go to trash and it won't let me right-click to send it to trash.

Comment: Reboot & try again. Also... are you using an admin account, or managed?

Comment: Admin account.  I'll try the reboot.

Comment: I rebooted but still can't get it to go into the trash can.  I tried another app I don't use and it went in just fine.

Comment: Thanks for you help on this.  I found the answer.  You have to drag it from the applications folder in Finder to trash.  I got this from the link: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7090389

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much.  I couldn't delete from the Application icon in my dock, but I was able to go to the Application folder in Finder.  I did not right-click, but I used the "trash can" icon I had added to the Finder toolbar.  That sent it to Trash (it made me enter the administrator password first), and I then emptied Trash and I was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had this problem repeatedly (including today) with the Mojave installer where it leaves behind the DMG file (5GB+) in the trash an nothing will delete it. The only way I have found to delete it is to

1. boot to recovery
2. mount the boot (data) partition
3. open Terminal
4. manually CD into the .Trash folder (or Users/user/.Trashes)
5. then `rm -rf "Install macOS Mojave”`